# How to use Guava cache instead of HashMap?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I have used `HashMap` for storing Fibonacci values.

Here is output from this code execution:

```
Enter n: 500000
F(500000) = 2955561408 ... computed in 5,141 ms
Enter n: 500000
F(500000) = 2955561408 ... computed in 0 ms
```

It caches just fine, and returns result just fine

I want to replace it with much better `Guava cache`, I have lost any profit.
Code execution output:

```
Enter n: 500000
F(500000) = 2955561408 ... computed in 5,184 ms
Enter n: 500000
F(500000) = 2955561408 ... computed in 5,086 ms
```

***Here is program code:***

```
public class CachedFibonacci {
    private static Map<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> previousValuesHolder;
    static {
        previousValuesHolder = new HashMap<>();
        previousValuesHolder.put(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO);
        previousValuesHolder.put(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE);
    }

    private static LoadingCache<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> cachedFibonacci = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .maximumSize(500000)
            .concurrencyLevel(5)
            .weakKeys()
            .build(new CacheLoader<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>() {
                @Override
                public BigDecimal load(BigDecimal key) throws Exception {
                    return getFibonacciByKey(key);
                }
            });

    private static BigDecimal getFibonacciByKey(BigDecimal key) {
        long number = key.longValue();

        BigDecimal olderValue = BigDecimal.ONE,
                oldValue = BigDecimal.ONE,
                newValue = BigDecimal.ONE;

        for (int i = 3; i <= number; i++) {
            newValue = oldValue.add(olderValue);
            olderValue = oldValue;
            oldValue = newValue;
        }
        return newValue;
    }

    public static BigDecimal getGuavaCache(long number) {
        if (0 == number) {
            return BigDecimal.ZERO;
        } else if (1 == number) {
            return BigDecimal.ONE;
        } else {
            return cachedFibonacci.getUnchecked(BigDecimal.valueOf(number));
        }
    }

    public static BigDecimal getCachedFibonacciOf(long number) {
        if (0 == number) {
            return BigDecimal.ZERO;
        } else if (1 == number) {
            return BigDecimal.ONE;
        } else {
            if (previousValuesHolder.containsKey(BigDecimal.valueOf(number))) {
                return previousValuesHolder.get(BigDecimal.valueOf(number));
            } else {
                BigDecimal olderValue = BigDecimal.ONE,
                        oldValue = BigDecimal.ONE,
                        newValue = BigDecimal.ONE;

                for (int i = 3; i <= number; i++) {
                    newValue = oldValue.add(olderValue);
                    olderValue = oldValue;
                    oldValue = newValue;
                }
                previousValuesHolder.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(number), newValue);
                return newValue;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter n: ");
            long inputNumber = scanner.nextLong();
            if (inputNumber >= 0) {
                long beginTime = System.nanoTime();
//                BigDecimal fibo = getCachedFibonacciOf(inputNumber);
                BigDecimal fibo = getGuavaCache(inputNumber);

                long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                long delta = endTime - beginTime;

                System.out.printf("F(%d) = %.10s ... computed in %,d ms\n", inputNumber, fibo, delta / 1_000_000);
            } else {
                System.err.println("You must enter number > 0");
                System.out.println("try, enter number again, please:");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I suppose when you call `cachedFibonacci.getUnchecked()` it should return cached value if it is cached, otherwise compute it and cache.

***Why does this code calculate it again with Guava cache?***
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Does "F(500000)" mean the 500,000th number in the Fibonacci sequence? Then the answer is definitely not correct, because that number is MUCH larger than 2955561408. Even F(48) is already a bigger number than that.

Comment: @Jesper I believe by "..." author meant rest of the digits.

Comment: @Jesper Yes, exactly.  I truncated output, for convenience. I have printed just first 10 numbers from fibo value.

Comment: @bezmax Exactly this. Otherwise result will be too looooong. Thanks.

Comment: @nazar_art I am wondering why you are using weak keys. I would suggest to remove that setting and check how the cache performs without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove line

```
.weakKeys()
```

from building cache, than you will see speed up of calculation.

From javaDoc

> - **Warning:** when this method is used, the resulting cache will use identity ({@code ==})
> - comparison to determine equality of keys.